# check value exists in database using general function Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller

I am studying codeigniter by developing a website locally. My doubt is, I added some fields in table as `unique`.

When I try to add duplicate values, It shows `internal server error`

I overcome this by add function for check if it is a duplicate entry. But I need to add this function on each table insertion.

My question is, **Is there any way to write a function at `My_model.php` for check a `table` and a `unique field value` and call it in the `My_controller.php` by passing the `table name` and `unique field value`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Codeigniter's default form validation to check if the new value being added to the unique field already exists in DB or not.

Refer this:

> **is_unique** | Returns FALSE | if the form element is not unique to the table and field name in the parameter.   is_unique[table.field]

this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email',
 'required|is_unique[users.email]');

Comment: Wow.. and it works..thank you for the answer. Will accept the answer once the waiting period over... :)